# Unity material is missing after compilation

Tags: c#, unity, collision-detection, shaders

I have a piece of code that signals the player that a projectile has hit its target. Everything works fine during the playmode, however after I compile it, it acts as if there was a missing material.

I did some trouble shooting, made 3 different builds with different settings, and I tried running the game with different quality, ranging from Fastest to Fantastic. Yet I can't find a cause of this problem.

```
IEnumerator flash() {
        rend.material.shader = specularShader;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashTime);
        rend.material.shader = defaultShader;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing this in the editor or after deploying the game to devices? Some shaders only work on certain devices.

Comment: I may try assigning a different shader in the script, I don't know why but I feel that it might be that the shader itself isn't included in project files, thus it will not be added into the compiled package. Yet it can be auto-included in unity editor.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the material in the scene, or is the material under a folder named "Resources"? If neither of the above is true, then Unity might not include the material when compiling an executable. It tries to prune unused assets, so if it can't find anything using the material (and it can't predict every possible execution outcome of scripts), and it's not in an always-included folder like "Resources" then it might be excluded from the build.

Comment: @DMGregory I think that it is the case here. I will check it later.